# Struts 2 get radio button value using javascript

Tags: javascript, jsp, struts2, struts

I have created a radio button using Struts tags however i am attempting to get the selected value of the radio button however i am unable to get the value. Under is what i have done thus far.

**Jsp**

```
<s:radio name="gender" id= "gender" list="#{'1':'Male','2':'Female'}" onChange="genderChange()"/>
```

**Javascript function**

```
function genderChange(){
 var gendervalue;
 genderValue = document.getElementById("gender").value;
 alert(gendervalue);

}
```

**Console Error**

```
TypeError: document.getElementById(...) is null
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution was for me to pass the element value into the java script function under is my updated code

**Jsp**

```
<s:radio name="gender" id= "gender" list="#{'1':'Male','2':'Female'}" onChange="genderChange(this.value)"/>
```

**Javascript function**

```
function genderChange(value){
 var gendervalue;
 genderValue = value;
 alert(gendervalue);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you see your page in HTML you can see that two radio buttons will be create, with 2 different ids: gender1 and gender2.
You can access to your value with:

```
var foo = document.getElementById("gender1").checked;
```

In this case, if the first is checked (foo==true), the other will be not checked.

A more scalable solution is using:

```
document.getElementsByName("gender")[index].checked
```

where index is a number that indentify all radio buttons with the name "gender". You can make a FOR to cycle the array and find at which index checked is true.

Comment: Your solution shows me how the get te value of an item in the group however I wish to get the value of the checked item. If items get added I woul have to modify my code to check the particular option. This isn't scalable for what I am trying to achieve. However +1 for your contribution and pointing out each item in the group has a different id